# How to type "µ" on a German keyboard in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

On a [German keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout), you can press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to type a `µ`. In Microsoft Edge, this seems to be an undocumented shortcut to trigger [“Make a Web Note”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17221/windows-10-write-on-the-web). Can one still natively do this without the use of the (possibly nonexistent) [numeric keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad)?

Comment: It appears that Microsoft Edge does not allow you to disable these shortcuts itself. How about using AutoHotKey to map the shortcut to what you want it to do? I don't have Microsoft Edge so can't tell if it works or not.

Comment: Just type this character in another application (note pad), copy it and paste it into MS Edge.